# BotMan - Conversations method is not replying

Tags: php, chatbot, messenger, botman

i am working on facebook messenger bot. I am using Botman (botman.io) without Laravel or botman studio. Version of PHP is 7.4.

Simple hears and reply method works fine, but conversation replying method does not working.

If I try type hi|hello or some greetings, chatbot answer me "Hello! What is your firstname?", then I write my name and chatbot does not returns any text :-/

Can you help me where is a bug?

There is a **conversation class**:

```
namespace LiborMatejka\Conversations;

use BotMan\BotMan\Messages\Conversations\Conversation;
use BotMan\BotMan\Messages\Incoming\Answer;

    class OnboardingConversation extends Conversation {

        protected $firstname;
        protected $email;

        function askFirstname() {

            $this->ask('Hello! What is your firstname?', function (Answer $answer) {

                // Save result
                $this->firstname = $answer->getText();

                $this->say('Nice to meet you ' . $this->firstname);

                $this->askEmail();

            });

        }

        public function askEmail() {

            $this->ask('One more thing - what is your email?', function (Answer $answer) {
                // Save result
                $this->email = $answer->getText();

                $this->say('Great - that is all we need, ' . $this->firstname);
            });

            //$this->bot->typesAndWaits(2);
        }

        public function run() {

            // This will be called immediately

            $this->askFirstname();

        }

    }
```

and there is **config**:

```
require_once "vendor/autoload.php";
require_once "class/onboardingConversation.php";

use BotMan\BotMan\BotMan;
use BotMan\BotMan\BotManFactory;
use BotMan\BotMan\Drivers\DriverManager;
use BotMan\Drivers\Facebook\FacebookDriver;
use LiborMatejka\Conversations\OnboardingConversation;

$config = [
    // Your driver-specific configuration
    'facebook' => [
        'token' => 'my_token',
        'app_secret' => 'my_secret_app_code',
        'verification' => 'verification_code',
    ],
    'botman' => [
        'conversation_cache_time' => 0,
    ],
];

// Load the driver(s) you want to use
DriverManager::loadDriver(\BotMan\Drivers\Facebook\FacebookDriver::class);

// Create an instance
$botman = BotManFactory::create($config);

$botman->hears('ahoj|hi|hello|cau|cus|zdar|zdarec|cago|hey|ciao', function (BotMan $bot) {
    $bot->startConversation(new OnboardingConversation);
});

// Start listening
$botman->listen();
```

Comment: Problem solved - i added symfony cache and it is ok now.

Comment: Hi, can you help me with the integration of botman in my symfony project ?

Answer (score 4):

Add symfony/cache to your project using composer

```
 composer require symfony/cache
```

Put following at top of index.php (or other) file where you're setting up BotMan

```
use BotMan\BotMan\Cache\SymfonyCache;
use Symfony\Component\Cache\Adapter\FilesystemAdapter;
```

Then create your BotMan using the following:

```
$adapter = new FilesystemAdapter();
$botman = BotManFactory::create($config, new SymfonyCache($adapter));
```

Then use your `$botman` variable accordingly, like example below:

```
$botman->hears('Hi', function (BotMan $bot) {
    $bot->typesAndWaits(2);
    $bot->reply('Hello and welcome');
    $bot->typesAndWaits(2);
    $bot->ask('Anything I can do for you today?',function($answer, $bot){
        $bot->say("Oh, really! You said '{$answer->getText()}'... is that right?");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I would rather to use auto-wiring to inject the SymfonyCache anywhere you create the Botman instance, without creating the adapter and cache again and again.

**Step 1:** config the cache in `cache.yaml`

```
framework:
    cache:
        # botman: cache adapter
        app: cache.adapter.filesystem
```

**Step 2:** autowiring in `services.yaml`

```
services:
    BotMan\BotMan\Cache\SymfonyCache:
        arguments:
            $adapter: '@cache.app'
```

**Step 3:** Inject the `SymfonyCache` where you need, for example in `ChatController::message()`

```
public function message(SymfonyCache $symfonyCache): Response
{
    ....
    $botman = BotManFactory::create([], $symfonyCache);
    ....
    $botman->hears(
            'survey',
            function (BotMan $bot) {
                $bot->startConversation(new OnBoardingConversation());
            }
        );
}
```

To create the OnBoardingConversation, just follow the documentation on [create a conversation in botman](https://botman.io/2.0/conversations#starting-a-conversation)